# iOS App going in suspended state in background when network is down despite the audio background mode is set

Tags: ios, swift, background, audio-streaming, ios-app-suspended-state

My app is an audio streaming app and else has the audio background mode is enabled.

When the app is in background streaming audio and the network is dropping, my app finally goes in suspended state after less than about 30 secondes after the network dropped (the audio streaming buffer is empty and we don't more ear anything).
Is it something normal for an audio streaming application that is supposed to "live forever" ?
Is there a way to avoid this so that the application in background can detect when the network comes back and resume the audio player ?

Thank you a lot for your feedbacks and similar experiences.

Comment: have you find solution ? my app is also going into suspended state and unable to run didreceiveremotenotification  on recieveing apns push.

Comment: Please add clarity to your question.  What do you mean "when the network dropped"?    Are you saying that you lose either TCP connection or UDP stream when you go to background?  Are you jut returning to the home screen?

Comment: I also note than if the app is waked up by the user asking to play again once the network is back via the remote control, the app switches from the suspended to the background state but :

Comment: Hi @jaybers, "when network dropped down" for is when you are no more connected to the wifi or 3/4/5G. When the user launch audio streaming in the app, he juste put the app in the background and do not interact anymore with the app. Exemple : when you are going to run (footing)

Comment: Hi @AmbeshTiwari, No i did not find any solution for now. In your case it's perhaps juste because you do not add capabilities background modes in your xcode project. You are always able to got notification push when an app is in background, even when the app is closed.